# What is http+s (firewall settings)

Tags: firewall, http

I'm able to configure my firewall settings for `http`, `https` and `http+s`, but I'm not sure what http+s is or could be used for?

Comment: What brand and model of firewall are you using if it's hardware we're talking about?  If it's a software firewall, are you talking about Windows Firewall or something else?  My guess would be that you can configure http, https, or both and that is what the http+s is; it designates both.

Comment: you are right http+s is for both, if you put that in an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this means, is that you can configure http, https, or you can configure them both with the http+s option.